# Terraform error because data block output returns Missing resource instance key

Tags: terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I just want to ignore the data block output while running plan step using Terraform OCI provider and I am trying to apply snapshot policy to my `oci_file_storage_file_system` resource. I have tried using the conditional count check but that does not seem to be helping.

What I expect: The snapshot policy ID is an optional parameter to oci_file_storage_file_system resource and ideally it should not fail if I do not provide any input but because I am doing a data lookup using a data block, if I do not provide any input to the data block it fails. **So what I want is to ignore the data block output if I do not pass any value through the tfvars. And if I do not pass any value it should just read the state if exists and not fail during plan or apply**

Here is the datablock

```
data "oci_file_storage_filesystem_snapshot_policy" "filesystem_snapshot_policy" {
    count        = var.internal ? 1 : 0
    availability_domain = var.availability_domain
    compartment_id = var.policy_tf_compartment_id
    display_name = var.filesystem_snapshot_policy_display_name
}
```

module code with resource block

```
resource "oci_file_storage_file_system" "file_system" {
  #Required
  availability_domain = var.availability_domain
  compartment_id      = var.compartment_id

  #Optional
  defined_tags       = var.defined_tags
  display_name       = var.display_name
  freeform_tags      = var.freeform_tags
  kms_key_id         = var.kms_key_id
  source_snapshot_id = var.source_snapshot_id
  filesystem_snapshot_policy_id = var.internal ? data.oci_file_storage_filesystem_snapshot_policy.filesystem_snapshot_policy.filesystem_snapshot_policies[0].id : data.oci_file_storage_filesystem_snapshot_policy.filesystem_snapshot_policy.filesystem_snapshot_policies[0].id
}
```

error

```
 Error: Missing resource instance key
 
   on .terraform/file-storage/fss/main.tf line 19, in resource "oci_file_storage_file_system" "file_system":
   19:   filesystem_snapshot_policy_id = var.internal ? data.oci_file_storage_filesystem_snapshot_policy.filesystem_snapshot_policy.filesystem_snapshot_policies[0].id : data.oci_file_storage_filesystem_snapshot_policy.filesystem_snapshot_policy.filesystem_snapshot_policies[0].id
 
 Because
 data.oci_file_storage_filesystem_snapshot_policy.filesystem_snapshot_policy
 has "count" set, its attributes must be accessed on specific instances.
 
 For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
     data.oci_file_storage_filesystem_snapshot_policy.filesystem_snapshot_policy[count.index]
```

Although I am not sure why I am getting this error as I am already calling the resource as an instance of the list.

Any help will be appreciated in helping how to ignore the data block output and use that in the resource block

Comment: It's probably because you're trying to index `filesystem_snapshot_policies` in either case of the `filesystem_snapshot_policy_id = var.internal` ternary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after some struggle I realized what I was doing wrong. Apparently I had to check the length of the returned array from the data block and if the length returns false then skip else check for the next condition. To return the array I did not need the `filesystem_snapshot_policies[0].id` and I did not need a count variable instead I could do this:
`filesystem_snapshot_policy_id = length(data.oci_file_storage_filesystem_snapshot_policy.filesystem_snapshot_policy.filesystem_snapshot_policies) != 0 ? data.oci_file_storage_filesystem_snapshot_policy.filesystem_snapshot_policy.filesystem_snapshot_policies[0].id : ""`

And that solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

The falsey return of the ternary in the `resource` needs to match the behavior of the corresponding ternary in the `data`:

```
filesystem_snapshot_policy_id = var.internal ? data.oci_file_storage_filesystem_snapshot_policies.filesystem_snapshot_policy[0].id : null
```

As requested in the question, this would ignore the value for a falsey value in `var.internal`, and is also expected behavior as no object attributes would be assigned to the `data` in this situation.

Note the error message is misleading in this situation, and it is therefore not surprising that you are confused by it.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response but I tried as you suggested and it is resulting in the same error

Comment: @DevOps_Engg I realized I retained a typo from the question content that generates the error, and that has been corrected. Otherwise the answer functionality does achieve the original request of only utilizing the `data` attribute when `var.internal` is truthy.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message

```
data.oci_file_storage_filesystem_snapshot_policies.filesystem_snapshot_policy
```

is an array (since it has a `count` attribute) so in order to reference one element you need an index such as:

```
data.oci_file_storage_filesystem_snapshot_policies.filesystem_snapshot_policy[0]
```

By the way the two options are exactly the same

```
filesystem_snapshot_policy_id = var.internal ? 
data.oci_file_storage_filesystem_snapshot_policies.filesystem_snapshot_policy.filesystem_snapshot_policies[0].id : 
data.oci_file_storage_filesystem_snapshot_policies.filesystem_snapshot_policy.filesystem_snapshot_policies[0].id
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are suggesting here. I have already tried what you have suggested above and although the 2 options are the same but results in 2 different errors. Any other suggestion that I can try?